# c# - Insert predefined value inside an array inside a string

Tags: c#

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
namespace Rextester{
    public class Program{
        public static void Main(string[] args){
            String[,] name = {{"Juan", "Pérez"}, {"Fred", "Nurk"}, {"Marko", "Marković"}, {"Si", "Polan"}};
            int place = 3;
            String _name = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(name[place,0])) ? $"Name: {name[{place},0]} {name[{place},1]}" : "Error";
            Console.WriteLine(_name);
        }
    }
}
```

I try to use the integer `place` inside the String `$"Name: {name[{place},0]} {name[{place},1]}"` as identifier for the array `name` but the compiler give me these errors back:

```
Compilation error (line 9, col 74): Identifier expected
Compilation error (line 9, col 80): Syntax error, ',' expected
Compilation error (line 9, col 92): Identifier expected
Compilation error (line 9, col 98): Syntax error, ',' expected
```

Why the compiler would not compile these line? The identifier is given, so I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Remove the braces from around place: `$"Name: {name[place,0]}...` etc.

Answer (score 2):

You already are inside curly brackets in the string, you don't need more curly brackets for each variable.

Not `$"Name: {name[{place},0]} {name[{place},1]}"`

But `$"Name: {name[place,0]} {name[place,1]}"`